# Neo4j returns null when restart spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I am working on a Spring Boot application that uses Neo4j for data storage,

I have a relationship of `SkillCategory` and `Skills`.
So one `SKillCategory` contains many skills.
Below is the Domain structure:

**Skill.java**

```
@NodeEntity
public class Skill extends BaseEntity {
    private String name;
    private boolean isVerified;
    private boolean isEnabled = true;
    @Relationship(type = SKILL_OF_LEVEL, direction = "OUTGOING")
    private SkillLevel skillLevel;

    public Skill() {
    }

    public Skill(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return isEnabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        isEnabled = enabled;
    }

    public boolean isVerified() {
        return isVerified;
    }

    public void setVerified(boolean verified) {
        isVerified = verified;
    }

    public SkillLevel getSkillLevel() {
        return skillLevel;
    }

    public void setSkillLevel(SkillLevel skillLevel) {
        this.skillLevel = skillLevel;
    }
}
```

**SkillCategory.java**

```
@NodeEntity
public class SkillCategory extends BaseEntity {
    private String name;
    private boolean isEnabled = true;
    @Relationship(type =  CONTAINS_SKILL,direction = "OUTGOING")
    private List<Skill> skillList;

    public SkillCategory() {
    }

    public SkillCategory(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public SkillCategory(String name, List<Skill> skillList) {
        this.name = name;
        this.skillList = skillList;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return isEnabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        isEnabled = enabled;
    }

    public List<Skill> getSkillList() {
        return skillList;
    }

    public void setSkillList(List<Skill> skillList) {
        this.skillList = skillList;
    }
}
```

I am using `GraphRepository` to perform CRUD operations.
I am creating `SkillCategory` & `Skills` on application boot.

Here is the problem: if I delete the DB & start Spring Boot, everything works fine.
But when I restart the Spring Boot application, `skillList` in `SkillCategory`
is null.

If anyone have experience in Spring Data Neo4j, kindly help me narrow down the issue.

Repository Code :

```
@Repository
public interface SkillGraphRepository extends GraphRepository<Skill>{
List<SkillCategory> findAll();
}
```

I assume that if i fetch skillCategory it'll automatically eager load to fetch skills in SkillCategory also

I am simply using a Service that injects SkillCategoryRepository

```
skillCategoryService.create(new skillCategory("Category1"),Arrays.asList(new Skill("Skill 1"),new     SKill("Skill 2")));
```

Comment: What version of Spring Data Neo4j are you using? Can you show how it's used, both for persistence and the code loading the entities, leading to the null collection? Are you specifying a depth?

Comment: @FrankPavageau depth is not specified, will post the rquired code in a while

Comment: Can you let us know which method in GraphRepository you are calling too? And as Frank mentioned can you let us know the SDN/OGM versions.

Comment: @digx1 
Hey man, sorry for late response
i am using
  springDataNeo4jVersion = "4.1.1.RELEASE"
  neo4jEmbeddedDriverVersion = "2.0.4"

Comment: Can you add the code that shows a bit more of what you are doing? Are you using `Repositories`? Need a little more info to work out what's going on.

Comment: @digx1
please check updated code

Comment: Can you add your test code too? How are you creating your skills?

Comment: @digx1 problem is that neo4j is inconsistent in loading related objects on requested Entity , sometimes it provides that the data sometimes it returns null

Comment: Are you calling save() on the skillGraphRepository before you restart the application?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125661/discussion-between-mohit-sharma-and-digx1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data disappearance between start ups was caused by starting SDN with the embedded driver and an impermanent data store.

When setting the driver to: `driver=org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver` you must also make sure you set a location for the Neo4j datastore `URI=file:///var/tmp/neo4j.db` to make data persistable between start ups otherwise your data will only exist while the application is running.

More details can be [found here](http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#_configuring_the_embedded_driver).